# In a topological space$X$ prove that $\overline A+\overline B\subseteq\overline {(A+B)}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space prove that  $\overline A+\overline B\subseteq\overline {(A+B)}$

where $A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$

**My attempt**

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map. Then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$, where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of an arbitrary set $A$.

so I consider $f=+$

would it be possible?

Comment: What exactly does $A+B$ mean?

Comment: Arthur, I edit it

Comment: What is $+$ in a topological space ? Is $X$ a topological vector space ?

Comment: And what does $a+b$ mean?

Comment: If X is a topological vector space then yes

Comment: @user62498 The $+$ object is a huge undefined mysterious elephant in the context of your problem. Probably you meant to consider a *topological magma* $(X, \cdot, \mathscr{T})$ and meant to inquire whether for any two subsets $M, N \subseteq X$ the relation $\overline{M}\cdot \overline{N} \subseteq \overline{MN}$ holds or not. And it does indeed hold.

Comment: I mean $X$ is a topological vector space

Comment: Aslo l like to know if $X$ just be a topological space how can we prove that?

Comment: @user62498 If $X$ is just a topological space, what would $+$ mean?

Comment: @user62498 If $X$ is *just* a topological space you can't even *formulate* what you intend to formulate, because the entity $+$ remains -- as many, myself included, have pointed out -- undefined. If $X$ is a topological magma -- in other words one for which the multiplication $\cdot X \times X \to X$ is continuous -- you prove the statement by applying precisely the relation you signaled above, using the operation $\cdot$ as the continuous map $f$ and bearing in mind that in the "direct square" topology on $X \times X$ you have $\overline{M \times N}=\overline{M} \times \overline{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if we are working in a topological vector space, or a more generally topological (semi)group $X$ where $p: X \times X \to X$ defined by $p(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous, then we can indeed apply the general fact that $f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f[\overline{C}] \subseteq \overline{f[C]}$ for all $C \subseteq X$. Note that $A + B = p[A \times B]$ by comparing their resp. definitions.

We apply it to $p$ and use $C= A \times B$ as the subset of its domain. In the product topology we know that $\overline{A \times B} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ and so as $p$ is continuous:

$$\overline{A} + \overline{B} = p[\overline{A} \times \overline{B}] = p[\overline{A \times B}] \subseteq \overline{p[A \times B]} = \overline{A + B}$$

as required.